# How to get actual number of channel in asterisk 13?

Tags: asterisk, dahdi

In asterisk 1.4 number of channel was specified in chan->name.
e.g. number 62:

```
asterisk 1.4 ZAPTEL: Zap/62-1
```

How to get actual number of channel in asterisk 13 in c-language?
e.g. in chan->name this number of span only.

```
asterisk 13 DAHDI: DAHDI/I2/102-1
```

Here is what R.Mudget say about extentons.conf:

> ```
> You can use the AMI action DAHDIShowChannels to get the current channel mapping.
>
> There is an AMI event that you can look for:
> Event: DAHDIChannel Channel: name Uniqueid: id DAHDISpan: 5
> DAHDIChannel: 23
>
> It is generated whenever a call is assigned to a B channel or a call moves to a different B channel.
>
> There is also the CHANNEL() dialplan function:
> CHANNEL(dahdi_channel)
> CHANNEL(dahdi_span)
> CHANNEL(dahdi_type)
>
> The DAHDIChannel event and CHANNEL() function are mentioned in the UPGRADE.txt file.
>
> Richard
> ```

But how do I get an actual number of channel in c-language API?

Answer (score -2):

Simplest way answer this question is read source code(writed in c/c++) of chan_dahdi and see how dahdi_channel variable is set in YOUR dahdi/asterisk combination.

You also can use ami from c/c++, but that is not optimal.

In general you should not see number of channel in channel-name unless you setuped one-channel-one-span.